# Putting the same URL shortcut on Windows 10 Taskbar for multiple users

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, windows-10, taskbar

I have an internal website with a URL link to http://subdomain.domain.com/etc/etc.  I'll have several hundred internal users that will access this URL/link and the method that I want ALL users to utilize to access this URL is from a shortcut on their Taskbar.  All users have Windows 10.  Almost all users default internet browser is either Chrome 74 or higher (32 or 64 bit) OR IE 11.1689.15063.0.  It's about 50/50 split.  For the few users with Edge or Firefox I'm not going to worry about.

I'm not in IT and not a programmer, I'm in Quality Assurance.  Just for full disclosure.

I created a shortcut on my desktop and pasted the URL for the Location.  I then drug this shortcut from my desktop into my Taskbar, but it automatically wants to Pin it to IE (or Chrome) instead of Pinning it to the Taskbar itself as a standalone icon (because I want all users to be able to just click the icon and it opens).

I also tried from within Chrome itself with the URL page pulled up, I clicked on the 3 dots, then More Tools, Create Shortcut, Named the shortcut, checked the box Open as window, and then clicked Create.  This created a desktop shortcut that DOES allow me to pin to my taskbar.  However, the issue here is that I want to be able to share the same shortcut with several hundred users.  So I sent the shortcut that I created to a guy that sits next to me, and the shortcut didn't keep the default icon and it also didn't open up the webpage.  So I'm thinking what I created must be unique to me/my computer.  I simply cannot ask 200+ users to perform the steps above to create this shortcut - I need it to be simple!

My goal is to create the Icon/Shortcut myself.  Then I'll place the shortcut into a shared network drive/location.  Then I email instructions to the 200+ users and ask them to copy the shortcut to their desktop and then copy it to their Taskbar.  But when copied to their Taskbar I need to make sure it won't pin it to their default browser (that's important!).  I need this to work for IE and Chrome users.  And I'm fine having 2 different shortcuts if that's what is necessary.  I can simply tell the users to choose either the IE or Chrome shortcut.  Again, I'm not a programmer!!!  In my head I'm assuming there's a way to build this shortcut so it doesn't pin to the default browser.

Hope it's okay to post this here.  Didn't know where else I this question would fit and I've had great success finding help here in the past so here we go!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, sharing shortcut directly seems impossible because this is usually  related to local machine configuration.

My suggestion is that you could share a command with your users so that they will open the URL from the IE/Chrome in their PC.

Here is a demo command that you could use it to open www.google.com in IE using Command Prompt.

```
@echo off
echo(
echo                     Launching Internet Explorer ...
Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.com"
:: Sleep for 5 seconds, you can change the SleepTime variable
set SleepTime=5
Timeout /T %SleepTime% /NoBreak>NUL
```

The iexplore is default in the path(C:\Program Files\internet explorer).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  The challenges that I'm having, and I could be doing something wrong, are:     1) I can't put a .bat and .cmd file onto the Taskbar (Windows 10 simply seems to not allow it).     2) when I replace 'www.google.com' with ' http : // subdomain . domain . com / etc / etc   (I input spaces as the full address isn't showing otherwise)... ' the website doesn't open so I'm assuming there has to be something special with the www vs http formatting?

Comment: What I mean by I added the spaces is that I only added spaces on this website because the sentence was automatically removing the HTTP part and making it a hyperlink, so the spaces are only here so I can illustrate the full URL (i.e. HTTP + subdomain + domain + ...).

Comment: With the suggestion that Jenifer gave, I would be good forcing IE and not worrying about Chrome as all users will for sure have IE installed since all users have Microsoft Windows 10.  Any other suggestions how to get a URL link into the task bar?  Internally someone showed me that once you open the link in IE, you can simply click the ICON in the URL window and drag to task bar.  This is sort of okay.  My issue with this is some users have already set Google Chrome as their default browser so when I email them the link and they click on it, their computer could open it in Chrome.

Comment: After you've used the command suggested above, then open the site in IE. Ask for your users to drag icon to the taskbar and the shortcut will link to the site in IE.[Demo animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu7yI.gif)